# Fourier transform and maximum

Tags: algorithm, fft

Is there a way to compute efficiently the Fourier transform of the max of two functions (f,g), knowing their Fourier transform?

Comment: Just to clarify: Do you mean you want the Fourier transform of the function whose value at each point is the max of the values of f and g at that point?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I doubt it. The Fourier transform of max(f, g) can be computed efficiently if and only if the Fourier transform of |f| can be computed efficiently. (Because max(f,g) = (f+g+|f-g|)/2.)

[But there seems to be no relationship between F{f} and F{|f|}...](http://www.mathworks.de/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/32772)

Answer (score 5):

Assuming you mean the max at each point, and since max is a non-linear operation, there is not going to be any way to do this. You would need to do the max operation in the time domain and then perform the Fourier transform.

Comment: "there is not going to be any way to do this." sign(x), heaviside step(x), ramp(x), cos(x), sin(x), exp(x) - they all are non-linear operation. And they all has Fourier Transform in sense of tempered distributions.

Answer (score 0):

You can stat with FT(max(f(x),g(x))) = FT( H(f-g)f + (1-H(f-g))f) = FT( H(f-g) f) + FT(1-H(f-g))f)

But here you will stucked because as I know there are no exist such cool formulas for compoistion of two functions.
Even if you know

FT(f)

FT(g)

FT(f-g)=FT(f)-FT(g)

FT(H)=1/2(delta+1/(pi i s))

Just open integral and figure out how to combine terms. It can be unbelievalbe hard or unbelievale simple. Just try.